# postgresql assert constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Is there a way to `ASSERT` in PL/pgSQL, but for an exception rather than a condition? i.e. assert that "violates X constraint" will happen.

The closest I could get was:

```
DECLARE xc integer DEFAULT 0;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [...];
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Should not make it this far';
EXCEPTION
    WHEN integrity_constraint_violation THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'Caught expected integrity violation';
        xc := xc + 1;
    ASSERT ((SELECT xc) = 1);
END;
```

This does the job(-ish). If I could specify the type of constraint violation that would be helpful.

Second part of question: how could I wrap this (or similar) into a macro / custom assert function?

Answer (score 0):

There are more specific SQL states for the specific constraint violations (see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/errcodes-appendix.html)), but essentially that's the best you can get unless you want to parse error messages (which is not a good idea).

You might also want to have a look at the [`ASSERT` statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSERT) in PL/pgSQL, which can be used to check conditions.